# MVT and twice differentiable function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Assume $f(x)$ is twice differentiable and $|f''(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in R$.

Fix $a \in R$. Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that for any $x \in R, x\neq a$, there is $c \in (x, a)$, such that
$$
f(x)-L_a(x)=(f'(c)-f'(a))(x-a)
$$
and
$$
|f(x)-L_a(x)|\leq M(x-a)^2.
$$

Here $L_a$ is the linearization of $f$ at $a.$

Comment: And what is $L_a$?

Comment: It is a linearisation

Comment: It is the linearization of $f$ at $a.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simply uses the function $g(x) = f(x) - L_a(f, x)$. We know $g$ is differentiable if $f$ is differentiable. So then by the mean value theorem, there is a $c$ so that
$$ \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a} = g'(c) = f'(c) - f'(a),$$
which rearranges into your desired equality.

For the second part, note that $f'(c) - f'(a) = f''(\xi)(c - a)$ for some $\xi \in (a, c)$, again by the mean value theorem. As $f'' \leq M$, we then know that $f'(c) - f'(a) \leq M(c-a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define $g(x) = f(x)  -L_a(x).$ Apply the MVT to $g(x) - g(a).$

Comment: I am still lost. Let $G(x)=g(x)-g(a)$, by MVT, there is $c \in (x,a)$, such that $G'(c)=(G(x)-G(a))/(x-a)=(f(x)-L_a(x)-f(a))/(x-a)$. How we would get the form they are asking?